# Android: ArrayList sort by type

Tags: java, android, list, sorting

I have `List<MyModel>` 
I need to sort the array in one of the fields (type), but not in alphabetical order -
in the following order - `["B, C, A"]`

How to change the code so that the first type was in the end?

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<MyModel>() {
   @Override
     public int compare(MyModel item1, MyModel item2) {
     return item2.type.compareToIgnoreCase(item1.type) ;
     }
});
```

Comment: How you defined that order ?

Comment: So that's the only values of type, "B", "C" and "A"?

Comment: so you have to organise your arraylist with a random order undefine ?

Comment: yes only those values

Comment: @Paul no random: first - all items with "B" type, second  - all items with "C" ans last - all items with "A" type

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Collections.sort(items, new Comparator<MyModel>() {
   private List<String> order = Arrays.asList("B", "C", "A");

   @Override
     public int compare(MyModel item1, MyModel item2) {    
         return order.indexOf(item1.type) - order.indexOf(item2.type);
     }
});
```

Or possibly reverse `item1`, `item2` if it's in the opposite order.